# Sort whole array in MATLAB (rows and columns simultaneously)

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a unsorted array

A =

```
10   -12     4     8
 6    -9     8     0
 2     3    11    -2
 1     1     9     3
```

I want to get it sorted fully and have the following result

A =

```
-12   -9    -2    0
 1     1     2    3
 3     4     6    8
 8     9    10   11
```

how can i do that?

Please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i want this way     A = [-12 -9 -2 0; 1 1 2 3; 3 4 6 8; 8 9 10 11]

Comment: If you need to add information or otherwise change your question, please just edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
A = sort(reshape(A,[1 16]));
```